# Android - is it possible to detect smile?

Tags: android, camera, detect

Is it possible to detect smile on android camera preview? I know that there is a FaceDetector class, but there I got only possibility to check the eyes ( from FaceDetector.Face ). Any SDK or examples? I know that this is possible, cause S3 got build in Smile detector, but could't find any other examples on Google Play Store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You Should Use 3rd party Face  Recognition Library.Facedetection.com has a decent list of opensource and commercial software for detection and/or recognition.

For face recognition, here's what I found on SourceForge:

> https://sites.google.com/site/elsamuko/c-cpp/opencv-facerecog
>
> http://facereco.com/

Then there are commercial offerings:

http://www.betaface.com

http://www.ayonix.com/
http://www.cognitec-systems.de